# Detecting XSS using url validation

Tags: php

What is a good url validation function in php to detect xss?

I tried the FILTER_URL function in php, but that still allows urls like:

```
http://example.com?<script></script>
```

Comment: "to detect xss" --- you cannot *detect* XSS, you may prevent it though.

Comment: You need to validate input rather than url.

Comment: Which `FILTER_URL` function you are talking about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php)

Answer (score 1):

You could try with these four tests:

```
// Set the patterns we'll test against
$patterns = array(
    // Match any attribute starting with "on" or xmlns
    '#(<[^>]+[\x00-\x20\"\'\/])(on|xmlns)[^>]*>?#iUu',

    // Match javascript:, livescript:, vbscript: and mocha: protocols
    '!((java|live|vb)script|mocha):(\w)*!iUu',
    '#-moz-binding[\x00-\x20]*:#u',

    // Match style attributes
    '#(<[^>]+[\x00-\x20\"\'\/])style=[^>]*>?#iUu',

    // Match unneeded tags
    '#</*(applet|meta|xml|blink|link|style|script|embed|object|iframe|frame|frameset|ilayer|layer|bgsound|title|base)[^>]*>?#i'
);
```

And instead of trying to detect XSS attacks, just make sure to use proper sanitizing.

Comment: @zerkms - wouldn't it be nice to explain what is awful and provide your solution, for the benefit of the OP and others seeking answer?

Comment: @raidenace: it's a valid question. Well, it's awful because it makes too much of decisions on what context it will be used in. We all know that XSS (and some other types of vulnerabilities, like sql injections) is a modification of a string that mutates resulting AST. From this point of view - the solution that **always** works (someone don't believe it for some reason though) - is to encode data according the context requirements. That's why this code is terrible. So, the solution that works for everyone in every case - is just to check the input format specification and **encode** data.

Comment: @zerkms - that's better. It is helpful to leave critiques along with 'thats just awful' sound bites.

Comment: @raidenace: now you see why the solutions are defined and known? Because the input formats are defined and known.

Comment: @zerkms - Please don't misconstrue. I only meant your response was better than the first. Nothing more.

Comment: @raidenace: oh... So you still think that html standard doesn't define everything one should know to write XSS-free code? Well, nothing to add here then, sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could use `htmlspecialchars()` and `strip_tags()` though they will not entirely prevent anything.

Use a combination of these as well as other heuristics. Ideally write your own function where you pass content through a chain of checks. filter_input can be used in it as well.